# Transmission line length with sag

Tags: transmission

I have a straight-line distance of 250 km between two towers and want to find the length of the transmission line that is between these two towers while accounting for the **sag**.

The line should be larger than 250 km. Given that the estimated sag is 60 m, how do I find the real transmission line? Can you provide me with references?

Comment: Going back to high school physics (don't ask how long ago that was) A uniformly loaded line like that hangs in the shape of a parabola.  You know the length and amount of sag, so it should be easy to calculate the total length of the cable.

Comment: And did you really mean 250 Km between towers?  That around 160 miles!!!

Comment: The shape of the curve is a catenary curve, not a parabola. If you search that, you should find plenty of information.

Comment: Read this: https://electricalengineerresources.com/2018/01/13/sample-calculation-of-sag-and-tension-of-transmission-line/

Comment: With 250km between them, these towers would need to be over 1km tall just to be able to see each other (unless we're in a parallel universe with a flat earth).

Comment: @SteveSh that's exactly what confused me. I have to find the parameters of this transmission line in this project I was assigned and believe me I am very confused.

Comment: @neurotech I'm wondering if the point of this exercise might be to demonstrate why towers are generally *not* put that far apart (or anywhere near that far apart!)

Comment: and a material for the line that will support its own mass over that distance...

Comment: You will not find a wire that can span that distance without breaking under its own weight, let alone the additional stress imposed by teh catenary curve. Useful search term : "breaking length".

Comment: It's OK. "Km" is kelvin-meters. It's not so far. Capitals matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are to problems with the question.

- Over 250 kilometers earth has 5 kilometers curve.
- the weight and tension in the cable are prohibiting to normal materials. W*125000/60 = approximate tension.

Otherwise there are many references online to solve a catenary self weight cable length.

Comment: I have a meeting with my professor in 30 mins, he requires from me to have these values. Anyhow, I'll ask if I have to account for the 5 kilometers curve, or does he want me to account for it. Everything else is set now. Thanks.